# How do I declare the isolation level of a stored procedure activity in ADF?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

This question is for all you ADF developers.

ADF sometimes gives control over our database isolation.  But that capability is only available for certain activities.

Surprisingly enough, Azure SQL Database uses a default isolation of RCSI. This isolation level has its pros and cons. As a result of this unusual setting in Azure, it is important for any database developer to be at least aware of the isolation, and fine-tune it where needed.

**In Regards to ADF:**

For the sake of some activities ("lookups" and "copy-data"), ADF allows us to declare the isolation that we require. This is great!  You can find that setting below.

[image]

However for a SQL "stored procedure" activity, there is no flexibility for declaring isolation levels. It means developers are required to alternate back and forth between declaring our isolation levels in the ADF tool (for lookups), or in the back-end SQL database (for stored procedures). The inconsistency is strange, and results in the need to sprinkle our conconcurrency-declarations in both places. This quickly becomes labor-intensive and redundant.  I would expect "stored-procedure" activities in ADF to have the same isolation-level options that we find in lookups .

Instead of declaring my isolation level in two places, **is there a better way to ensure that both the "lookups" and the "stored procedure" activities in ADF are always using the same concurrency strategy**?

Sometimes it doesn't feel like ADF is robust enough, if it can't help me specify my isolation level when making stored procedure calls.  Database developers need to have control over the concurrency strategy, for certain projects.

Comment: Please do not repost questions; there is an edit feature which can send your post to the review queue for reopening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True. You currently cannot set the Isolation Level for Stored Procedure Activity. Your only 2 options as of now are:

**Script Acitivty** Use a Script Activity and Run your Stored Procedure from there. Before Executing stored procedure you can set the Isolation Level.

```sql
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
EXEC YourStoredProcName @Param1, @Param2, ...;
```

**Custom Activity** Create a Custom Acitivity, which is more involving

Set Up Azure Batch Account:

Create an Azure Batch account in the Azure portal.
Ensure you've also set up a linked storage account for the Batch account.
Develop Custom Code:

You can write your code in a language of your choice, like C#, Python, etc.
Ensure your code performs the desired operations, including setting the desired transaction isolation levels or any other database-specific operations.
Package Code in a Docker Container:

Dockerize your application. Create a Dockerfile that specifies how your application is built and run.
Build and test the Docker container locally to ensure your code executes correctly.
Push your Docker image to a container registry, like Docker Hub or Azure Container Registry.
Integrate with ADF:

In ADF, create a pipeline.
Add a 'Batch Service' linked service. Configure it to point to your Azure Batch account and the pool.
Add a custom activity to your pipeline. Point the activity to the 'Batch Service' linked service you just created.
Specify the Docker image URL and the command to run in the container.

Comment: Second makes sense but too much trouble IMO.

Comment: Thank you for these options.  These  seem to progressively take us further away from the "low-code/no-code" goals of ADF.  It is helpful to get confirmation that I'm not missing something obvious in this tool.  I had found the inconsistencies a bit unsettling (because a SQL stored procedure has just as much reason to declare isolation as a "lookup").  I wonder how many people abandon ADF for their pipeline development, as soon as some small feature-gap arises (like this one).

Answer (score 1):

ADF, the low-code tool as it is, is of course going to struggle to catch up in fine-tuning options compared to code. I thought about this but I couldnt help but think about a function. Second thing that came to my mind was databricks activity.

In your case, you could create an Azure Function (in the pipeline) that executes the stored procedure with the desired isolation level and returns the result. This allows you to centralize the isolation level configuration within the function. You can use the output of that isolation level later in the pipeline.

Another option is Databricks notebook (or python?) activity: In the Databricks notebook, you can execute the procedure and configure the isolation level explicitly using sparksql settings. This approach should give you more control and allow you to fine-tune the isolation level. But again, you might be limited by sparksql here, you can just use something else to code. and sorry for not giving a low-code option.

Comment: Yes, we started moving more of the actual database interactions out of ADF pipelines and into a couple of "real" (Spark-hosted) programming platforms (python and .Net).  I'm guessing it is a natural progression to start with a low-code/no-code approach and then advance to doing more general-purpose programming in another runtime.  However it would be nice if ADF would at least help developers to be a bit more consistent, when interacting with databases.  Without that isolation level selection, they may not think about this concern up front, until the deadlocks start happening.

Comment: @DavidBeavon, I am sure there is a feature request for this in ADF somewhere. After 5 minutes going through all related feature requests I have seen, I havent been able to find one about isolation level for Storproc activity. They dont care much about these, I have already 2 open but it might help :) maybe its a development in progress. File one here: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community

Comment: those feedback sites of Microsoft's are pretty discouraging for me.  In the past they often delete all the ideas for arbitrary reasons (usually under the pretext of a "technical migration from one platform to another")   Based on watching the evolution of a number of products, I think these things are not actually used by PG. (they are last in a long line of concerns...  they care about money first, then support cases, then strategic direction of the product, and so on.  They may get to the "ideas" if they ever get bored and have nothing to do that day ;-)

Comment: @DavidBeavon, having worked with PG (as a middle escalation) for several Azure products, I can tell you PG are a very busy bunch! their priority from our side seems to be catching the bugs instead of finding new ideas for development. But this seems like a development issue that PG will look at if you raise it, because its not been raised it seems! But if they found the idea unimplementable, they just leave it as it is, which they shouldnt do.

Comment: I added my feedback.  Hoping you will contribute one more vote?  Maybe it will lead to some new functionality in three to five years. ...

 https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/09950ba9-443a-ee11-a81c-000d3a040137

I'm guessing they left this out of the ADF implementation for one good reason or another.  A "stored procedure" is such a generic concept, and I'm guessing they need to provide that sort of activity for lots of unrelated data sources.  Any feature that doesn't have parity across all the data sources will probably be excluded.

Comment: @DavidBeavon, I upvoted your idea, lets hope it gets implemented. If its unimplementable, you will at least know why (I hope). :)